# Python Big O Determination

Tags: python, performance, time, time-complexity, big-o

I'm writing a program where I have to determine the growth rate of some code.

It might be run like this:

```
python3 my_program.py program_with_code_to_test
```

Here is where I am stuck:

The executable code accepts one int argument `n`. I can assume that "N0" (that is N subscript zero), is equal to 2^10 which is = 1024, and that every N is another power of 2.

So I know that the data size doubles every time. I need to determine how the growth rate in time changes.

SO if

```
some_code 1024 # 1024 being n
```

Takes 0.5 seconds to execute and

```
some_code 2048 # = 2^11
```

Takes 0.5 seconds to execute. Then I know that the growth rate is constant, i.e. the time it takes is irrelevant to the data size. One more example:
if

```
some_code 1024 # takes 0.5 seconds
some_code 2048 # takes roughly 2.0 seconds
```

then I need to output that the Big O time is quadratic (because the time it takes for the program to execute roughly quadruples as the data doubles).

So I think I need to do something like this:

```
before = time.process_time()
# whatever code I am passing in
after = time.process_time()
totalTime = after - before
```

But then how can I save totalTime so that I can see how totalTime changes as N (or the data size) doubles? How can I compare totalTime with the last totalTime? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? Thanks for any help.

Note: Now I know I need to use subprocess.call for my code but I will figure that out later.

Comment: Empirical tests are not really how you determine Big Oh. If your big-oh analysis is correct, then it is giving you a *worst case* scaling behavior.

Comment: Well all I have to determine is whether the growth rate is either: constant, logarithmic, linear, linearithmic, quadratic, or cubic.

Comment: Right, I gathered, just wanted to lay that out there in case you cared to clarify. Also, I have no idea what your command line arguments do, let alone what `some_code` is suppose to represent... I fear you might just be reinventing the `timeit` module.

Comment: Hmm I wish there was more info I could give you, hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Comment: If you have access to the source code--which I'm guessing you do, because I'm guessing you wrote it!--then the right way to determine big-O is by looking at the code execution, loops, recursion, etc., and reasoning about how execution time would vary with N...

Comment: @AlexL Lol yes I know I could do that but I am trying to write a program that does that.

Comment: Oh, I get it :-}